# Why are tabs lost after click side menu?

Tags: tabs, ionic2

I start my project with tabs template and then I add side menu into it. Both tabs and side menu work, but if i click on menu item, page lost tabs view.

**app.components.ts**

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage = TabsPage;

  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(public platform: Platform) {

    this.initializeApp();

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Home', component: HomePage },
      { title: 'About', component: AboutPage },
      { title: 'Contact', component: ContactPage }
    ];
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
```

**app.html**

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" push persistent=true>
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content class="outer-content">
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>    
</ion-menu>    
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Comment: I found that my problem is component to set root. thanks all!

Comment: Hi, i know it is an old question but i would have been interested to know how you did since i'm facing the same issue. Not sure what you mean by "is component to set root".

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are setting the component selected from the menu as **root**.

```
this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
```

This *replaces* the existing TabsPage with the selected page as root rather than change the selected tab of the TabsPage.

A solution is to send the page object from `openPage()` function to TabsPage using  [Events API](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) or a service with Observable/Subject.

```
openPage(page) {

    this.events.publish('menu selected',page);

  }
```

In your TabsPage,

```
ngOnInit(){
this.events.subscribe('menu selected',this.openPage.bind(this))
}
openPage(page){

  this.tabs.select(page.index);//set an additional property with index same as tab order.
}
```